# How to show status from dropdown value October CMS List

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I am using October CMS and and am very new to it. am using one of its plugin called as "Builder" http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder and so far so good.

But I am stuck at one stage and confused how to do this. my case is below.

I have created one new field called as "status" in my one of the plugins in which I have key values like (0=>Inactive, 1=>Active) . this works fine and am able to insert or update values to db.

But the thing is, when i go to listing page, i have selected a "status" field but its showing me values 0 or 1 instead of Active or Inactive.

How can i show Active or Inactive instead of 0 and 1 using builder plugin or any other way. it will ne greateful if someone can help me out to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it using builder is you can use `switch` list type.

As those drop-down values are for form field. If you want to sync them then we need to write custom code for that. but I guess for your solution `switch` is better alternative.

> Set type to `switch`

[image]

> Output in list

[image]

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: I am unable to use switch since am having issues with some other fields like type etc..is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: can you share your issue because you just need to use it in list so it wont affect anywhere else in forms etc..